# Create new remote git repo

Tags: git, github

I`m very confuse about git basics.
I have a local branch "develop" and I created a new local branch  "branch_1" from "develop" using command: git checkout -b branch_1.

I need to create a remote branch "branch_1" on GitHub and connect my local branch "branch_1"  to it, but I`m not sure what is the proper way to do it. Since "branch_1" is not exist yet on GitHub, how I can create it from terminal? In my previous attempt, I created a new branch using GitHub website and ended up with an orphan branch. Can anyone provide me with the next step, please?

---

I used git push and got: The current branch branch_1 has no upstream branch. To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use
git push --set-upstream origin branch_1

After I executed this command, it created a new branch branch_1 on the Git Hub.

Comment: You just need to do `git push` on your local branch , enter your credentials and voilà, the local branch is in github.

Comment: I`m not sure if I do git push, to with branch on GitHub it will go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without needing to create any new branches directly on GitHub, you should be able to run

```
git push -u origin branch_1
```

(or whatever your remote name is instead of origin). This will automatically create the new remote branch `branch_1`and set up your local `branch_1` to track it.